# How does the curiosity rover get it's power?

Tags: energy, nuclear-physics, nuclear-engineering

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mars Curiosity Power System](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/34203/mars-curiosity-power-system)

I found a web page that said it uses Plutonium. I am sure it's not based on fusion or fission. What is the basic idea on which the power plant works?

Comment: A recent question answered this: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/34203/mars-curiosity-power-system

Answer (score 2):

Curiosity uses a [radioisotope thermoelectric generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radioisotope_thermoelectric_generator).

> A radioisotope thermoelectric generator (RTG, RITEG) is an electrical
>   generator that obtains its power from radioactive decay. In such a
>   device, the heat released by the decay of a suitable radioactive
>   material is converted into electricity by the Seebeck effect using an
>   array of thermocouples.